# How to Create a process in c++ to execute exe?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to execute an `.exe` which is available on some drive. How can I do this using C++?

I am doing it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
    
void main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if(!CreateProcess(L"c:\\DOTNET.exe",NULL,NULL, NULL,FALSE, 0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi ) ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Prcess Creation Success");
    }

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread ); 

    getch();
}
```

But every time, it is showing this error:

```
process creation failed with error code 2 (i.e can not find the path specified)
```

But I place the `DOTNET.exe` at `c:\DOTNET.exe` only.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Is the difference between c:\ and c:\\ just a typo? And have you tried system(...) instead of CreateProcess(...)?

Comment: Can you run "c:\\dotnet.exe" from the command line?

Comment: i am tested it is running properly from command line.

Comment: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: Your code works, try to launch other files to see if dotnet.exe is not locked or something like this.

Comment: YUP MY CODE IS WORKING..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your code and it's working here with :

```
if(!CreateProcess(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",NULL,NULL, NULL,FALSE, 0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi ) )
```

A C++/Win32 solution for your C/Win32 code :)

```
void ExecuteAndWait (wstring toto)
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
    vector<TCHAR> V( toto.length() + 1);
    for (int i=0;i< (int) toto.length();i++)
    V[i] = toto[i];
    CreateProcess(NULL, &V[0],0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a Unicode executable?  Try _T("C:\\DOTNET.exe") instead.

Or does your DOTNET.exe have some dependent DLLs which are not being found?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call CreateProcess() differently.

Try this;

```
if (!CreateProcess( NULL, L"C:\\DOTNET.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
```

Comment: then it gives the exception as 
Unhandled exception at 0x77e4ba89 in CreateProc.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00415696.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll keep looking at it and see if I can reproduce your problem, at the moment it works in my test app.